# How to draw pixel-perfect geometric shapes and patterns?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, graphics, image-processing

When designing user interfaces, games and other visual applications, very often you have to have an image with a well defined geometric pattern. Some examples:

- A placeholder image of given size with a 1px red border:

  [image]
- A 64x64 sized image with black background and a white circle exactly in the middle that fades out towards the edges, to be used as a mask texture:

  [image]
- A grey triangle with given angles and edge lengths in pixels:

  [image]

What's a good way to create these kind of regular shapes? Currently I'm just using image processing apps like Pixelmator, but the results are not very optimal, because you have to guesstimate a lot. It's more trial & error than exact rendering. The white circle in the example above is probably not even in the middle exactly.

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem. Divide image dimensions by 2 and you have the center for your circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might give ImageMagick a try. Here's an example from their page of [drawing examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/):

```
convert -size 100x60 xc:skyblue -fill white -stroke black \
        -draw "path 'M 30,10 20,55 70,50 80,5 Z
                     M 50,20 60,40 40,30 Z' " path_with_hole.gif
```

This produces this image:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!